# WPF - Use ViewModel to change label content

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding

During rendering of MainWindows(and some other windows), the application performs multiple operations(connecting to some servers etc...). I want to show real time status of these connections(some of them lasts for couple of seconds) to users. I tried using ViewModel this way:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

public NotifyViewModel()
    {
        //_changeNameCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnChangeName);
        ConnectionStatus = "Not Connected";
    }

    private string _connectionStatus;
    public string ConnectionStatus
    {
        get => _connectionStatus;
        set => SetProperty(ref _connectionStatus, value);
    }

public MainWindow()
    {            
        try
        {
            _notify = new NotifyViewModel();
            DataContext = _notify;
            _log.Info("Starting main window...");
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log
        }
        
    }


private void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            _notify.ConnectionStatus = "Connecting...";
            _s.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _notify.ConnectionStatus = "Error connecting, contact administrator";
        }
                 
    }
```

The application only shows the first status, and shows the status after execution, but doesent change anything during execution.

what am I doing wrong?

Also if someone can recommend some tutorials on the net regarding MVVM, I would be much thankful

Comment: When `_s.Connect();` is blocking the UI thread, the UI will not receive any updates. Make the method async, or wrap it in a Task like `await Task.Run(() => _s.Connect());`. this requires that the view model's Connect method is declared as `private async Task Connect()` and also awaited when called.

Comment: What is `_s` and where do you actually set the `ConnectionStatus` property during the execution?